# How to find the most efficient way to group data based on values in 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a DataFrame with the following entries:

```
In[7]: test = [["Red",10],["Red",5],["Blue",10],["Green",10],["Blue",10],["Red",15]]
In[8]: df = pd.DataFrame(test,columns=['Color','Price'])
Out[8]:
   Color  Price
0    Red     10
1    Red      5
2   Blue     10
3  Green     10
4   Blue     10
5    Red     15
```

I want to group this data by either `'Color'` or `'Price'`, and find the most efficient way to do this such that the results will have the least number of groups.

I'm looking for a way to get the following solution:

```
   Group    Price                     Color
0      0  [5, 15]                     [Red]
1      1     [10]  [Red, Blue, Green, Blue]
```

Finally, is there an easy way to map the data under column `'Group'` back to the original table like this:

```
   Color  Price  Group
0    Red     10      1
1    Red      5      0
2   Blue     10      1
3  Green     10      1
4   Blue     10      1
5    Red     15      0
```

I've tried to use groupby on `'Color'` and `'Price'` individually and reached the following results:

```
# groupby 'Color'
In[10]: df = df.groupby(['Color'],as_index=False)['Price'].agg(list).reset_index()
In[11]: df.rename({"index":"Group"},axis=1,inplace=True)
In[12]: df.head()
Out[12]:
   Group  Color        Price
0      0   Blue     [10, 10]
1      1  Green         [10]
2      2    Red  [10, 5, 15]
```

```
# groupby 'Price'
In[13]: df = df.groupby(['Price'],as_index=False)['Color'].agg(list).reset_index()
In[14]: df.rename({"index":"Group"},axis=1,inplace=True)
In[15]: df.head()
Out[15]:
   Group  Price                     Color
0      0      5                     [Red]
1      1     10  [Red, Blue, Green, Blue]
2      2     15                     [Red]
```

However, I'm not sure how to combine these results to get my desired results shown above.

I'm quite new to data analysis, and I apologise if my question is too elementary, but I haven't managed to find a solution so far. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The logic is unclear why do you combine 5/15 and not 10?

Comment: @mozway sorry for the confusion, I want to achieve the least number of groups possible while grouping by either 'Color' or 'Price', but I'm not limited to grouping by only one or the other. My desired solution seems to be the only way I can have 2 groups instead of 3 in this case, I may be wrong...

Comment: @ZhangYuhan but where does `15` come from in `[5, 15]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it comes from the last row entry of my dataset, ['Red', 15]. I grouped it with the other 'Red' entry with price of 5 to have the minimum number of groups.

Comment: @ZhangYuhan, your last entry is `["Red",5]`. Check your input

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry you're right I didn't realise I had typo, should be fixed now, thanks :)

Comment: what if the data is equally balanced like `[["Red",10],["Red",10],["Blue",12],["Green",12],["Blue",15],["Green",15]]` ? what should be the result?

Comment: First groupby using the column having least number of unique values. Now on that grouped output - apply groupby again using the other column.